# Using formulas for calculation in R

Tags: r

I would like some help to solve a calculus issue involving the R software. I did one part, but I didn't understand the other part very well, so I would like your help.

I used three multicriteria methods (MCDM), which I will call `M1`, `M2` and `M3`, to generate ranks, which is the `result` database. That was the first step.

```
 result<-structure(list(n = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
         12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 
         28, 29), M1 = c(29L, 1L, 28L, 27L, 25L, 26L, 24L, 20L, 21L, 
         22L, 23L, 15L, 12L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 16L, 13L, 14L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
         8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 4L, 2L, 3L), M2 = c(1, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 
        24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 15, 12, 19, 18, 17, 16, 14, 13, 11, 10, 9, 
       8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2), M3 = c(1L, 29L, 28L, 27L, 25L, 26L, 24L, 
       20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 15L, 12L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 16L, 13L, 14L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 4L, 
       2L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-29L))

> result
    n M1 M2 M3
1   1 29  1  1
2   2  1 29 29
3   3 28 28 28
4   4 27 27 27
5   5 25 26 25
6   6 26 25 26
7   7 24 24 24
8   8 20 23 20
9   9 21 22 21
10 10 22 21 22
11 11 23 20 23
12 12 15 15 15
13 13 12 12 12
14 14 17 19 17
15 15 18 18 18
16 16 19 17 19
17 17 16 16 16
18 18 13 14 13
19 19 14 13 14
20 20  5 11  5
21 21  6 10  6
22 22  7  9  7
23 23  8  8  8
24 24  9  7  9
25 25 10  6 10
26 26 11  5 11
27 27  4  4  4
28 28  2  3  2
29 29  3  2  3
```

The second step utilizes `Spearman’s rank correlation coefficient` to find the weights for each MCDM method. `Spearman’s rank correlation coefficient` between the `kth` and `ith` MCDM methods is calculated by the following equation:

[image]

where `n` is the number of alternatives and `di` is the difference between the ranks of two MCDM methods.

So I did like this:

```
pki<-cor(result[,2:4], method = "spearman")

> pki
          M1        M2        M3
M1 1.0000000 0.5778325 0.6137931
M2 0.5778325 1.0000000 0.9640394
M3 0.6137931 0.9640394 1.0000000
```

The third step is as follows: Based on the value of `pki`, the average similarities between the
`kth` MCDM method and other MCDM methods can be calculated as:

[image]

where `q` is the number of MCDM methods.

This third step I didn't quite understand, so I don't know how to do it, can you help me???

Comment: Set the diag to 0, take the sums and adjust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
rho2 <-rho # “pki” -> rho[k,i]
diag(rho2) <- 0
rowSums(rho2)/2 # 1/(3-1) == 2
```

Do note the the term “formula” does not apply here when discussing R. That mathematical equation is really describing a set of mathematical operations. R formulas have several uses with the most applicable here being to describe model structures. The closest term to search on might be expression or function if you were trying to encapsulate this into a single object.